# Host Data Object set to Null Reference Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a multi player game. And doing a check OnGUI() that if there is any hostData do something.

```
if (hostData)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < hostData.Length; i++)
   {
       GUI.Button (new Rect (btnX * 2f + btnW, btnY * 1.2f + (btnH * i), btnW * 3f, btnH * 0.5f), hostData [i].gameName);
   }
}
```

But  I have filled host Data on a button click, while on the other hand OnGUI is always looking for if(hostData) that is why it gives Null reference.

How i check this if statement other then this. Help me out.

Comment: `if (hostdata)` should return false when hostData is null, effectively skipping the for loop. Where do you actually get a null reference?

Comment: on if(hostData) line. This worked in JS but i am doing it in C#. Is that a problem..?

Comment: Okay, so is `hostData` being set by dragging something into the component variable within the editor? Or is `hostData` being set programmatically during runtime? Either way, you need to figure out why `hostData` is null.

Comment: Not in Editor. it is programmatically set when user clicks a button. And that is why it gives NULL error, because it is always being checked in OnGUI.

Comment: SOLUTION:  I did this and it worked:

if (hostData != null) 
now it is not giving error.

Comment: Ah I get it now. `hostData` is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (hostData)` only works if hostData is a game object, or component. This is because Unity implemented the [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx).

In other words, `if (gameObject)` works as a shortcut to `if (gameObject != null)`.

This doesn't work when you are using something else then game objects or components, such as arrays or lists. In that case you have to use `!= null`.